# Client bandwidth usage with Ruby's net/http

Tags: ruby, linux, networking

I am trying to track the bandwidth usage of individual requests in ruby, to see how much of my network usage is being split between different API calls.

Nothing I can find in net/http or ruby socket classes (TCPSocket, et. al) that seems to have a decent way to do this with out much monkey patching.

I have found a number of useful tools on linux for doing this, but none of them give me the granularity to inspect inside the http requests at the headers (so I could figure out which url we are requesting). The tools I am using are vnStat and ipfm -- which are great system bandwidth or host/network monitoring.

Ideally I would like to do something within the ruby code to track the data sent/received. I think if I could just get the raw header and add that length to the body length for both transfer and receive that would be Good Enough™.

Comment: [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) will let you dig into those HTTP headers. You should also be able to do it with [TCPDump](http://www.tcpdump.org/) and you can probably drive TCPDump from Ruby as a subshell.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use [New Relic for Ruby](https://newrelic.com/docs/ruby/new-relic-for-ruby)? It has great visualizations/graphs for network usage/api calls.

Comment: Don't think so. This is for a ruby client application, not a web app.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it would be pretty easy to write a middleware to track this using [Faraday](https://github.com/technoweenie/faraday).